# c# Upgrading Build Environment to 2017 causes Runtime Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

We are working with Visual Studio 2015 and .Net 4.5 for our project.
As the project grew bigger, we wanted to set up a build environment instead of building on the developer workstations.

We used chocolaty to install "microsoft-build-tools 15.0.26320.2" which is a visual studio 2017 build environment. The chocolaty packages requires the .Net 4.6.2 package.

All our projects reference ToolsVersion 14.0 and TargetFrameworkVersion v4.5. The project files look like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" ...>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

The project compiles and runs without any issues if .Net 4.6.2 is installed on the target system. If only .Net 4.5 is installed we get errors when trying to start the Programm.

The line of code that causes this issue is

```
string.Format(new CustomFormatProvider(), "{0:fs}", value);
```

The compiler referenced the static method String.Format(IFormatProvider, string, object) which was introduced in 4.6 instead of String.Format(IFormatProvider, string, param object[])

Can anyone tell me, how to make tell the MSBuild.exe to only use methods that were already available in .Net 4.5 ?

Comment: Can you just install .Net 4.6+ on the target system? If not, can you install an older version of MS build tools and directly reference that MSBuild.exe path?

Comment: I just installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and executed the script referencing the new exe with version "14.0.23107.0" and it behaves the same way.
Changing the requirements because we can't handle our build process? The product owner would not like that...